# ¿ordenar vector de estructura de datos por codigo ? C++ (con uso de ficheros)

Tags: c++

hola necesito ayuda en mi código pero no me funcionan al momento de realizar la impresión en orden por código me podrían decir mi error o un mejor método para el ordenamiento también utilice el std::sort pero  mostraba errores

```
struct CLIENTE{
    char codigo[5]="";
    char nombre[20]="";
    char telefono[9]="";

};
//función para ordenar el array de empleados por el método de la burbuja
void burbuja( CLIENTE A[], int N){
    int i, j;
    CLIENTE aux;
    int tamanio=sizeof(aux);
    for(i=0;i<tamanio-1;i++)      
        for(j=0;j<tamanio-i-1;j++)
            if(A[j+1].codigo<A[j].codigo) 
            {               
              aux=A[j+1];   
              A[j+1]=A[j];  
              A[j]=aux;
            }
}
void ordenced(){
    CLIENTE cliente, *array;
    int tamanyo = sizeof(CLIENTE); // Tamaño de un registro
    int i = 0, num_registros;
    ifstream in;
    in.open("personas.dat");
    if(in.fail())
    {
       cout << "Error al abrir el fichero" << endl;
       system("pause");
       exit(1);
    }

    //cálculo del número de registros del fichero
    in.seekg(0,ios::end); //nos posicionamos al final del fichero
    //número de registros = bytes / tamaño en bytes de un registro
    num_registros=in.tellg()/tamanyo;

    //creamos el array con el tamaño calculado
    array = new CLIENTE[num_registros];
    if(array==NULL)
    {
       cout << "Error en la asignación de memoria\n";
       system("pause");
       exit(1);
    }

    in.seekg(0); //volvemos al pincipio del fichero
    // Pasamos los registros al array
    in.read((char *) &array[i], tamanyo);
    while(!in.eof())
    {
         i++;
         in.read((char *) &array[i], tamanyo);
    }
    
    burbuja(array,num_registros); //ordenar el array
   
    //mostrar todos los empleados ordenados por sueldo
    for(i=0;i<num_registros;i++)
    {
            cout << "\nEMPLEADO: " << i+1 << endl;
            cout << "Codigo: " << array[i].codigo << endl;
            cout << "Nombre: " << array[i].nombre << endl;
            cout << "Telefono: " << array[i].telefono << endl;
    }
    in.close();
    delete [] array;
    system("pause");
}
```

al momento de obtener un ejemplo de igreso puede ser

```
7   Maria  0975435678
3   Juan   0985432456
5   Miguel 0764689907
```

lo que espero obtener es lo siguiente:

```
3   Juan   0985432456
5   Miguel 0764689907
7   Maria  0975435678
```

Comment: Creo que el `for` en la funcion `burbuja` esta mal. Supongo que tienes que hacerlo sobre el tamaño del array, que seria `N`.

Answer (score 0):

Esto no hace lo que crees:

```
int tamanio=sizeof(aux);
```

Dado que `aux` es de tipo `CLIENTE`, el valor será el tamaño de ese tipo que son unos 34 bytes, esto implica que tu algoritmo de ordenación sólo funcionará como esperas si añades 34 registros (no tres como estás añadiendo).

Posiblemente querías hacer esto:

```
void burbuja(CLIENTE A[], int N) {
    for (int i = 0; i != N - 1; ++i)      
        for (int j = i + 1; j != N; ++j)
            if (std::atoi(A[i].codigo) < std::atoi(A[j].codigo)) 
            {               
                std::swap(A[i], A[j]) 
            }
}
```

Fíjate que he corregido tu algoritmo de ordenación que además de recorrer los bucles mal comparaba mal los valores (comparabas punteros entre si, no los códigos) y que para simplificar he usado la función [`std::swap`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap) de la cabecera [`<algorithm>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/algorithm).

Si además sobrecargamos para `CLIENTE` los operadores de lectura y escritura a archivo el código se simplifica aún más:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

struct CLIENTE{
    char codigo[5]="";
    char nombre[20]="";
    char telefono[11]="";
};

std::ofstream &operator<<(std::ofstream &o, const CLIENTE &c)
{
    o.write(c.codigo, 5);
    o.write(c.nombre, 20);
    o.write(c.telefono, 9);

    return o;
}

std::ifstream &operator>>(std::ifstream &i, CLIENTE &c)
{
    i.read(c.codigo, 5);
    i.read(c.nombre, 20);
    i.read(c.telefono, 9);

    return i;
}

int main()
{
    if (std::ofstream o{"datos.txt"})
    {
        o
        << CLIENTE{"7", "Maria", "0975435678"}
        << CLIENTE{"3", "Juan", "0985432456"}
        << CLIENTE{"5", "Miguel", "0764689907"};
    }


    if (std::ifstream i{"datos.txt"})
    {
        for (CLIENTE c; i >> c;)
        {
            std::cout << "Leido cliente " << c.nombre << '\n';
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZFfb4IwFMWf4VPcdIliwgj@QUQYL4sPW9ye9ub2wEp1TbA1tWRLjJ@dXUBQcSNpaM45ufeXU7rb3dMsEZuiuOOCZnnKIOJyrxVLtrF51taNZOIlpxoel0@L17fFwQT86FeigMqUb@TK@3ggJDzLQm4/FVuN3I6uWcbWUsjVcFg7x7Acns7n8rQMenLHVKKliiKr69i4T@xbDujRgXkwDel8K66ZRZ0axwZvEF7KNY4NI/dab3BsCNAwDcV0rgRI5Dph8RusOLY6Dre7QNxBJ@3ytOo1Tiv/Q8MrGi40bBMurHrBGjrlyANJEW/v6B9NjgPTwJQh8URR@2zEJzaQl0TxpLy4ge9Nxt7Un5FjJzgu/ec8EXVuhrnRxJve5LxqIN/kLKuS/nQynQWB6xN8WAOxL1DbwvhfqGupwGpqpCFwiGP8o1vZRjWCylwD7idLxlMJNONMaAak1Jpay3v/XfRxPwKUDE2RLhZZFL8)</kbd>

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, me fue de mucha ayuda, no conocía la función std::swap y tambien por hacer notar los errores que tuve.